# MySQL - Uso de AND & OR en la misma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla como ésta, que tiene dos filas:

```
nombre_per   | apellido_per   | permisos_busqueda_per
-------------+----------------+----------------------
Mattew       | Janeey         | SI
Janny        | Pineda         | NO
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per 
FROM   la_tabla 
WHERE  nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%' AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI"
```

Si estoy buscando solo los usuarios que tengan habilitado el permiso para ser buscados (`permisos_busqueda_per`), ¿por qué me da como resultado las dos filas si Janny no tiene habilitada el permiso de ser encontrada?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Esto es un problema con la precedencia de los operadores, como puedes ver en la [documentación de MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html), el operador AND tiene preferencia sobre el OR, esto hace que tu SELECT seleccione basándose en estas condiciones:

- gente que tenga un nombre con la letra "a"; O
- gente que tenga un apellido con la letra "a" Y permisos iguales a "SI"

cuando realmente lo que quiere es esto:

- gente que tenga un nombre o un apellido con la letra "a"; Y
- permisos iguales a "SI"

La solución es simple: usa paréntesis:

```
SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per 
FROM   la_tabla 
WHERE  (nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%') AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI"
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba agrupando las condiciones con parentesis

```
SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per FROM la_tabla WHERE (nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%') AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en la consulta, tienes que cambiar:

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per FROM la_tabla WHERE nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%' AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI"
```

Por esto:

```
    SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per FROM la_tabla WHERE nombre_per LIKE '%a%' AND permisos_busqueda_per= 'SI'
 OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%' AND permisos_busqueda_per= 'SI'
```

El problem estaba en el 'or'. Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Cómo han comentado en las otras respuestas tu problema está en que los operadores según la [documentación](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) no siguen el proceso que esperas; te recomiendo que cuándo utilizes operaciones lo hagas así:

```
SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per 
FROM   la_tabla 
WHERE  (nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%') 
        AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI"
```

Separando en distintas líneas los AND y siempre utilizando `()` en cada línea.

Answer (score 0):

Eso mismo, además no estoy seguro sobre mysql, pero en sql tienes que usar comillas simples para los strings, es decir ' en lugar de "

Answer (score 0):

otras personas ya lo han documentado, pero lo que tienes que saber es que el orden de los factores influye mucho en las consultas, te trae los dos valores porque lo ultimo que lo ultimo que esta haciendo es el OR, es por eso que debes meterla dentro de los paréntesis para diferenciar entre una operación de otra y no pueda confundirse el gestor

SELECT nombre_per, apellido_per, permisos_busqueda_per 
FROM   la_tabla 
WHERE  (nombre_per LIKE '%a%' OR apellido_per LIKE '%a%') 
        AND permisos_busqueda_per="SI"

Debes recordar que el orden de ejecución en este caso despues del Where va primero los parentesis y luego el AND, 
ya seleccionó todos lo que su nombre y apellido tiene una "a" y despues procede a verificar los permisos

Espero te sea de ayuda la información